# Cookie popup not storing. reappears once user hits refresh despite selecting accept

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, popup

I need help getting this code to run properly. it appears as expected. Responds to click action however once the page is refreshed it reappears which means the js is not working as expected and the cookie is not being stored once the accept is clicked.

```
 **HTML**
```

Popup appears however once page is refreshed. Which I assume means the cookie is not being stored. I would like the cookie to be stored for 30 days.  I am not sure what's wrong with the code.

```
    <!-------------Cookie Notice

 
     popup------------>
            <div id="cookieNotice" 
     class="light display-right">
                <div id="closeIcon" 
     style="display: none;">
                </div>
                <div class="title- 
     wrap">
                    <h4>This website 
     uses cookies</h4>
                    &ensp;
                </div>
                <div class="content- 
     wrap">
                    <div class="msg- 
     wrap">
                        <p> We use 
     cookies to personalize and improve 
     your experience on our site and to 
     serve you relevant content. Visit 
     our  <a style="color:#115cfa;" 
     href=""> Privacy Policy</a> for 
     more information on our data 
     collection practices. By clicking 
     Accept All Cookies, you agree to 
     use our cookies.</p>&ensp;
                        <div 
      class="btn-wrap">
                            <button 
      class="btn-primary" 
     onclick="acceptCookieConsent(); 
    ">Accept All Cookies</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


**JavaScript**

**// Create cookie**
    function setCookie(name,value,days) {
        var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";

**// Delete cookie**
    function deleteCookie(cname) {
        const d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000));
        let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=;" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

**// Read cookie**
    function getCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    **// Set cookie consent**
    function acceptCookieConsent(){
        deleteCookie('user_cookie_consent');
        setCookie('user_cookie_consent', 1, 30);
        document.getElementById("cookieNotice").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // set cookie visibility
    let cookie_consent = getCookie("user_cookie_consent");
    if(cookie_consent != ""){
         jQuery('#cookieNotice').show()
    }
    else{
        jQuery('#cookieNotice').hide()
    }


This is the CSS I'm using to style the popup box. I want it bottom left.

**CSS**

    #cookieNotice {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 1rem;
        left: 1rem;
        background:#fff;
        z-index: 2051;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 21px;
        color:rgb(39, 36, 36);
        border-radius: 6px;
      
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      
         > div:first-child;
          width:650px;
        }
      
        a {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      
        #closeIcon {
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .btn-primary {
            width: 10em;
            font-size: 18px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background:white;
    
        }
      
        @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
      
          > div:first-child {
            width: auto;
          }
        }
```

I would like the cookie to be stored for 30 days.  I am not sure what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Please add code as text. Images of code are not acceptable.

Comment: updated to code